# PHP while loop inside a foreach loop only retrieves one record

Tags: php

Ok, I'm mystified.  For some reason this combination of loops is only returning one city record.  I have an array of zip codes ($`locationzips`).  I can run through them all, but only one associated city is returned, even though the foreach loop completes properly.  I've checked the database table and the zip codes are there with the correct cities.  What am I not seeing?

```
foreach ($locationzips as $key => $zip) {
    $getcities = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM us WHERE code = '$zip'");
    echo 'test zip: '.$zip.'<br>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcities)) {
        $city = $row['city'];
        echo 'test city: '.$city.'<br>';
    } 
}
```

This returns:

```
test zip: 34110<br>
test city: Naples<br>
test zip: 34145<br>
test zip: 34135<br>
test zip: 33928<br>
test zip: 33901<br>
test zip: 33904<br>
```

Comment: What does count(mysql_fetch_assoc($getcities)) tell you?

Comment: what does the sql returns? As not in the php but as in phpmyadmin? It might be that there is an error in your query?

Comment: try `$city[]` instead of `$city` ( in case of multiple result ) and then write `var_dump($city)`

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to see whether the query actually works

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `$getcities` query isn't returning the results like you expect. Double check with `mysql_num_rows($getcities)` or `echo "SELECT * FORM us WHERE code = '$zip'";`

Comment: Try it with setting `$getcities` to a `NULL` after each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for all of these quick responses! Was still befuddled after trying all of your suggestions and still not getting anywhere until I suddenly noticed there was a space after each comma in the array... which is why it would still print out the zip code, but couldn't find it in the database. It's not the first time a space has thrown me off.  Probably won't be the last either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) I cannot reproduce the behaviour with the following script + sample data

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error());
setup();
$locationzips = array(34110,34145,34135,33928,33901,33904);

foreach ($locationzips as $key => $zip) {
    $getcities = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tmp_us WHERE code = '$zip'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'test zip: '.$zip."\n";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcities)) {
        $city = $row['city'];
        echo 'test city: '.$city."\n";
    }
}

function setup() {
    mysql_query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_us (
            id int auto_increment,
            city varchar(64),
            code varchar(16),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ') or die(mysql_error());

    for($code=33901; $code<=34145; $code++) {
        foreach(range('a','d') as $foo) {
            $city = $code.'_'.$foo;
            $stmt = sprintf("INSERT INTO tmp_us (city,code) VALUES('%s','%s')", $city, $code);
            mysql_query($stmt) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

b) You don't need multiple queries when e.g. using the IN operator

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error());
setup();
$locationzips = array(34110,34145,34135,33928,33901,33904);


$stmt = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tmp_us WHERE code IN ('%s') ORDER BY code", join("','", $locationzips));
$getcities = mysql_query($stmt) or die(mysql_error());
$current_code = null;
while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getcities)) ) {
    if ( $current_code!=$row['code'] ) {
        $current_code = $row['code'];
        echo 'zip: ', $current_code, "\n";
    }
    echo '  city: ', $row['city'], "\n";
}

function setup() {
    mysql_query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_us (
            id int auto_increment,
            city varchar(64),
            code varchar(16),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ') or die(mysql_error());

    for($code=33901; $code<=34145; $code++) {
        foreach(range('a','d') as $foo) {
            $city = $code.'_'.$foo;
            $stmt = sprintf("INSERT INTO tmp_us (city,code) VALUES('%s','%s')", $city, $code);
            mysql_query($stmt) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
zip: 33901
  city: 33901_a
  city: 33901_b
  city: 33901_c
  city: 33901_d
zip: 33904
  city: 33904_d
  city: 33904_c
  city: 33904_b
  city: 33904_a
zip: 33928
  city: 33928_a
  city: 33928_b
  city: 33928_c
  city: 33928_d
zip: 34110
  city: 34110_d
  city: 34110_c
  city: 34110_b
  city: 34110_a
zip: 34135
  city: 34135_d
  city: 34135_c
  city: 34135_b
  city: 34135_a
zip: 34145
  city: 34145_a
  city: 34145_b
  city: 34145_c
  city: 34145_d
```

c) the mysql extension is marked as depreacted. Use something like [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) instead

Comment: Nice!  I like your little bit of code using IN.  Much slicker.  And yes, I'm going to check out PDO.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your table looks like, I would say this is an expensive way to do this. I'd suggest creating an array all the cities from your table and keying them with the zip code. You'd be eliminating the need to run the query multiple times.

```
    $cities = mysql_query("SELECT * from us");
    $cityArray = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($cities, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $cityArray[$row['code']] = $row['city'];
    }

    foreach($locationzips as $zip) {
        print 'Test Zip:' . $zip . '<br>';
        print 'Test City:' . $cityArray[$zip] .'<br>';
    }
```

I could start a rant about not using, the mysql extension (ie the mysql_*) functions...I won't but will only say, you should think about replacing them; PHP will be deprecating and removing them. Consider using PDO or MySQLi going forward. I think you'll find the above block more efficient and easier to test/debug.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  US is actually a table of all the zip codes in the USA, so I wouldn't do well to put all those cities into an array.  I will follow up on using PDO or MYSQLi in the future, however.  I hadn't heard about the mysql_ thingy being deprecated yet, so I appreciate the heads up.